# Enhance Pandas performance by adding more computational power

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I'm running Pandas data wrangling with several nested functions on a 1gig+ csv file (one of possibly many). I've tried various code optimization techniques and I'm still not happy with the performance. I realize there are possible optimizations with Cython etc. which I have not explored. Before I go with further complex code optimizations I would like to understand some most natural next steps with throwing more comp. power at the problem.

What techniques would you suggest trying first? I understand going the Spark route would require rewriting many of the Pandas operations to Spark frames. I also read about Dask. Any suggestions, advantages/disadvantages would be welcome.

Comment: It's incredibly difficult to say why you're seeing "slow performance" when we don't know anything about your code or your data. Can you give us an example of either, or ideally both?

Comment: Hi Asongtoruin, I'm afraid this is not really of use. I already tried breaking this down into smaller chunks and optimize the code. But I feel I would first explore "hardware" options at this stage, so that's more of a tooling question.

Comment: I'm not a pandas expert and !i might be wrong here!, but often algorithmics and in numpy/pandas-world vectorization matter more than buying more hardware. There are probably real use-cases, but the *term* "several nested functions" is often an indicator for under-optimized code. The first thing to do is of course profiling (but maybe you did that; even if not presented here). It's hard to get a feeling how good your approaches in terms of this (imho) first-layer of optimization are (no numpy/pandas tags in profile) and maybe maybe you are just looking for the wrong (more painful) alternatives

Comment: Have you profiled your code?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I did look at the performance of individual functions, did cut all the loops and moved to more vectorized approach. Nested functions is wrong wording I used. I will keep looking at code optimization options, but in case somebody has some hints on the tooling/hardware side, I will appreciate it.